# Constructors of built-in types

Tags: python

Python documentation describes intrinsics (special attributes) of most built-in types ([Data model](https://docs.python.org/3.10/reference/datamodel.html), [`inspect`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/inspect.html)). All these types are given constructors, which allows to create entities thereof. For example, a function object could be created by the line
`foo = types.FunctionType(...arguments...)`. VS Code pop-up input helper says there are six arguments, gives their names. But as far as these constructors are not documented, it's a bit challenging to grab enough information on them. Could you please help with this?

Comment: I think it's un(der)documented for a reason. The best/only documentation I am aware of is in the docstring (see `help(types.FunctionType)`), which only lists *five* arguments. (Maybe VS Code is including an implicit class argument?)

Comment: I also think the fact that you can create a `function` object by calling `types.FunctionType` is more of an implementation-specific side effect rather than the intent of exposing the types via the `types` module. Rather, they are there to make `isinstance` checks cleaner. (`FunctionType`, for example, is simply defined as `type(_f)` where `_f` itself is just defined with a trivial `def` statement.)

Comment: (And `LambdaType` is defined separately, even though currently `def` statements and lambda expressions produce values of exactly the same type.)

Comment: @chepner Regarding 5 vs 6 arguments, [the docs say](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/types.html?highlight=functiontype#standard-interpreter-types): *"note that signatures may vary between Python versions."*

Comment: Why do you need more information on them? What are you trying to accomplish exactly? I'm not sure why you'd want to instantiate `FunctionType` instead of using a `def` statement. Beware the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/343832). It'd also help to [edit] your post and ask an explicit question, like for example, "Where can I find more information on the constructors of built-in types like `FunctionType`?". See [ask] for tips on that.